# React : Material UI cannot display message (Snackbar)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, alert

I created a custom Alert as shown below, but when I add Snackbar, it is not displaying. Here is the part that I changed, the rest is the same:

***AlertPopup:***

```
const AlertPopup = () => {
  const { text, type } = useAlert();

  if (text && type) {
    return (

      // when I use this, the message is displayed
      // <Alert variant="filled" severity={type} sx={{}}>
      //   {text}
      // </Alert>

      // when I use this, the message is NOT displayed
      <Stack spacing={2} sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Snackbar autoHideDuration={6000}>
      <Alert variant="filled" severity={type} >
        {text}
      </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
      </Stack>

    );
  } else {
    return <></>;
  }
};
```

Here is the other parts of the implementation. I did not changed other parts (`AlertContext` and `useAlert` classes) as there is not specific component for Alert:

So, what is missing with this implementation?

Comment: Just curious ... Is there a particular reason you would want to use an alert and a snackbar simultaneously since a snackbar can be an alert with a warning or error type?

Comment: My instinct is that alerts usually stop DOM propagation, which is why the snackbar is not displayed when added before the snackbar

Comment: @Jamie_D Actually I am beginner on React and may have applied something wrong. So, could you share your suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visibility of the [Material UI Snackbar](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/snackbar/) is controlled by the **open** property. Typically, some change in the state of your component would trigger the display of the Snackbar. See [the basic example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/#simple-snackbars) from the docs.

Your code could be updated like this:

```
const AlertPopup = () => {
    const [ open, setOpen ] = React.useState( false );
    const { text, type } = useAlert();

    React.useEffect( () => {
        // Test for some condition that triggers the display of the Snackbar.
        if ( <Snackbar should be displayed> ) {
            setOpen( true );
        }
        
        // Dependencies array: see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects
    }, [ <Dependencies array: includes value(s) used by the effect for the test condition> ] ); 

    if (text && type) {
        return (

            // when I use this, the message is displayed
            // <Alert variant="filled" severity={type} sx={{}}>
            //     {text}
            // </Alert>

            // when I use this, the message is NOT displayed
            <Stack spacing={2} sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
            <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000}>
            <Alert variant="filled" severity={type} >
                {text}
            </Alert>
            </Snackbar>
            </Stack>

        );
    } else {
        return <></>;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. Actually I think I need a proper implementation that will display errors in a different message. I tried with this, but it uses the same container. So, would you suggest an elegant global implementation with Snackbar ?

Comment: @Chris Pratt It depends on whether you want to display messages for all errors all at once, or display them one by one to give the user an opportunity to take actions on each error individually. If it is the former, you can collect all the messages and display them in a MUI Dialog. If the latter, you could use [consecutive snackbars](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/#consecutive-snackbars).

Answer (score 1):

It may be silly but try to wrap it into a single JSX element

Comment: Could you post an example by providing global component?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).