# How to format error messages as list in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, error-handling, material-ui

I return the following response from Spring Boot API and want to format properly on my React app:

```
Array(4)
0: {field: 'lastName', message: 'size must be between 3 and 50'}
1: {field: 'username', message: 'size must be between 3 and 20'}
2: {field: 'password', message: 'size must be between 6 and 100'}
3: {field: 'firstName', message: 'size must be between 3 and 50'}
```

I have the following alert method that displays messages. But I cannot format the message by including all the error messages by type:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  postWithoutAuth("/auth/signup", formValues)
    .then((response) => {
      setAlert("Signed up successfully", "success");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      error.response.data.errors.foreach(e => {
        setAlert(<li>{e.field + " " + e.message}</li>);
      })
    });
};
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you wrap your inputs in a FormControl wrapper to allow you to use the error function?

Comment: Thanks for help. I can use error function, but the problem is displaying multiple errors properly. Could you post an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four things

1. you are in JS so `<li>{e.field + " " + e.message}</li>` needs to be `"<li>" + e.field + " " + e.message + "</li>"`
2. you are pumping a lot of alerts in quick succession.
3. `forEach()` is case sensitive. You have `foreach()`
4. the `severity` on `setAlert()` is missing

Presuming that `error.response.data.errors` contains the array in your question, try the following:

```
.catch((error) => {
  var alertContents = '<ul>';
  error.response.data.errors.forEach(e => {
    alertContents += "<li>" + e.field + " " + e.message + "</li>\n";
  });
    setAlert(alertContents + </ul>, "error");   
});
```

Comment: It sounds good, but unfortunately throws "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: error.response.data.errors.foreach is not a function at Signup.jsx:70:1". Any idea?

Comment: That error message means that error.response.data.errors is not an array. Add the following before the error.response.data.errors.foreach. console.log('error', error); Expand the result recursively in console, screengrab and add to the question.

Comment: Tried, but gives still the same error.

Comment: `console.log(console.log(error.response.data.errors))` gives this -->  `(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{field: 'firstName', message: 'size must be between 3 and 50'}
1
: 
{field: 'username', message: 'size must be between 3 and 20'}
2
: 
field
: 
"password"
message
: 
"size must be between 6 and 100"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
3
: 
{field: 'lastName', message: 'size must be between 3 and 50'}
length
: 
4
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)`

Comment: `console.log(error.response.data.errors[0].field)` gives this --> `username`

Comment: forEach is case sensitive. Fixed my answer. I hate JS.

Comment: The problem was not passing `severity` parameter. Now I fixed by `setAlert(alertContents, "error"); `. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have a problem similar to this. Do you have an idea >>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75711650/react-material-ui-cannot-display-message-snackbar